# "Terminal" would like to administer your computer. Administration can include passwords

Tags: terminal, cron

I am trying to automate crontab addition in Mac Catalina 10.15.5 via command:

```
echo -e "* * * * * \run.sh"|crontab -
```

this command replicates **crontab -e** command and adds the required crontab in the system.

But it asks for permission which is not removable via automation.

[image]

a. Sudo command requires user to enter password, which is again not possible to be automated.

b. Tried creating a file and then adding it to crontab via **crontab filepath**, but that also requires above elevation.

Comment: `echo -e "\r"` is going to print a carriage return, no?

Comment: may be. But here I am giving echo -e "cron_expression filename_to_run"

Comment: I'm just saying that the command you show will create garbled output because of `\r`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, latest Mac OS have put additional layer of security and can't be bypassed.

But I found following workaround. Since I am not changing system, so following solution works for me.

I have to give full access to program via:

System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access -> Add Program.

[image]